# Java + Selenium Object per Class

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium + TestNG in Java for web Automation. Currently I have set up my automation such that I have a static web driver and every call to webdriver returns the same browser instance.

Though this has been easier for me to develop different modules(no need to pass the object), now I am facing issues when trying to run TC in parallel.

I would like to know if there is any way I can create a webdriver for each testcase and use the same webdriver through out the same test case without actually passing that object to the various modules?

Ex :  I have testcase TC1 , testcase TC2

I have module 1 , 2 , 3 which are called by both TC1 and TC2. I need to create two webdriver object W1 and W2 such that all the methods in TC1 use W1 and all in TC2 use W2 without me passing W1 and W2 explicitly to all the modules.

Thank You

Comment: The above information is not enough to solve your problem. Can you post the code of TC1 and TC2 and how they are calling the module 1,2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Create webdriver instance as a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) object.  This way your instance would be global across your thread and kind of local only to the thread triggered due to parallel runs.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Base class with a Non-static webdriver object initialization.
- Extend the said BaseClass across you test classes.
- Depending upon the step at which you need to initialize the webdriver object use the @Before and @After annotations for initializing and quitting your driver object in your base class.